# How to allow a variable part including slashes in the route?

Tags: routes, kohana, kohana-3.3

For example:

```
mysite.com/questions/test/1
```

And I want to know if it's realy contains a string `test` with id which is `1` in this example.

Note. It's not a standart controller vs action and id. I must to check this and set the route(`controller` vs. `action`) for this.

add. The reason is this part `mysite.com/["questions/"]test/1` can contain any amount of words, like `mysite.com/a/b/c/d/test/1`, but the end of the url is always `test/(id)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify the regular expression for each part of the route and thus allow additional `/`. Your route could look like this:

```php
Route::set('test', '<question>/test/<id>',
    array(
        'question' => '[^.,;?\n]+',
        'id' => '\d+',
    ))
    ->defaults(array(
        'controller' => 'Test',
        'action'     => 'index',
    ));
```

`<...>` [evaluates to](http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide/kohana/routing#regex) `[^/.,;?\n]++` - so remove the slash (since you want to allow it) and the additional plus and you have the one you looked for.

The URI `/foo/bar/hello/test/5` will now be caught and you'll get the parameters

```
Array
(
    [question] => foo/bar/hello
    [id] => 5
)
```

accessible via [`$this->request->param()`](http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide-api/Request#param)